# Рандомный выбор из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Всем добрый день. Столкнулся с небольшой проблемкой. Подскажите решение. Нужно сделать вывод материалов из БД, допустим, по 30 штук на страницу. Дальше появляется навигация например 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, и т.д. страницы. Проблема заключается в следующем: как сделать рандомный вывод 30 материалов и чтобы они не повторялись ни на одной странице?

Comment: Какой примерный размер данных в таблице?

Comment: пока что около 3000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делайте так.

1. Пусть `n = count(*)`. Заведите случайную перестановку набора чисел `0 .. n-1`. Для этого можно использовать, например, алгоритм [Фишера-Йетса](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Пусть переставленные числа `p[0]`, `p[1]`, ..., `p[n-1]`. Перестановку необходимо сохранять между последовательными переходами то страницам.
2. При запросе `i`-й страницы прочитайте из базы и выдайте записи с номерами `p[k]` для `k` от `30 * i` до `min(30 * (i+1), n) - 1`.

Comment: Можно наглядный пример ??? а то на словах не совсем улавливаю.

Comment: Ну, пускай у вас всего 13 записей, и вы хотите выдавать по 4 на страницу. Генерируем перестановку чисел 0 1 2 ... 12, например:

    3 12 7 9 1 2 6 0 11 10 4 8 5

и запоминаем. При запросе страницы 0 выдаём материалы 3, 12, 7, 9. При запросе страницы 1 выдаём материалы 1, 2, 6, 0. При запросе страницы 2 выдаём материалы 11, 10, 4, 8. При запросе страницы 3 выдаём материал 5.

Comment: А запоминать я так понимаю в массив ?? и потом гетом передавать при переключении страниц ??

Comment: Запоминать где угодно, можно и в массиве, вы ж архитектор системы. Насчёт передачи GET'ом не понял — всё должно происходить, понятно, на стороне сервера, откуда взялся GET?

Comment: Тогда как можно передавать значение из страницы в страницу ??

Comment: @alexsis20102: вы серьёзно спрашиваете или прикалываетесь? отслеживайте пользователей, храните на сервере данные по каждому пользователю.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант добавить в таблицу уникальное поле `sub_id` с типом `int` и атрибутом `unsigned`, выполнить следующий запрос

`UPDATE table SET sub_id=ROUND(RAND()*10000)`

А выборку делать

`ORDER BY(sub_id)`

Остальное можно додумать

Comment: @Palmervan: вроде не покатит, если пользователей больше 1. И `RAND()*10000` не гарантированно уникален.

Comment: Надо проверить все варианты ))) Спасибо за еще один

Comment: @VladD тут мозгами дошевеливать нужно, и пробывать-пробывать... то что RAND() не уникален - это понятно, можно цифру увеличить.